# Having problems when removing duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

So I am trying to remove duplicates from an array. The array is made from strings.

```php
$string = "B+,A,A,A+,C,B,B,";
$okay = explode(",", $string);
array_pop($okay);
$newarray = array_unique($okay); 
for ($x = 0 ; $x < count($newarray) ; $x++) {
  echo $newarray[$x];
}
```

However, when I try to run it, for some reason, it says the following:

`Warning: Undefined array key 2 in Standard input code on line 14`

I do not know what is causing this. I think that array_unique just removes that element at that space, hence `$newarray[2]` is undefined. If so, are there any ways that I can use to display the new array properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
for ($x = 0 ; $x < count($newarray) ; $x++) {
  echo $newarray[$x];
}
```

you could use:

```
foreach ($newarray as $value) {
  echo $value.'<br>';
}
```

circumventing the problem with the keys completely.

If you want to show the keys as well you could do:

```
foreach ($newarray as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key = $value<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'm new to php so I didn't knew that function existed!

Comment: @3061LRTAGSPKJMORMRT Yeah, `foreach` is nice in combination with arrays.